# Hibernate Query - Complex

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm dabbling in SQL at the moment and would love some help on a problem that I've created.

To practice some programming i'm making an IOU app. Below is the table I store
my IOU records (ignoring some relevant columns). This table allows users to say "Hey, you owe me X amount of money" and "I owe you X amount of money".

```
| Creator    |    Type     | User_Involved| Amount |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|   
| 1          |    0        |     2        |   3.0
| 2          |    0        |     1        |   4.0
| 3          |    1        |     1        |   5.0
```

Note: Type represents if the user has "lent or requested money".
      0 = Lent
      1 = Requested

Goal: My goal is to get a list of all Users and their total owed amount (negative or positive).

This has become quite difficult as I can't do a simple group by, as there are two columns i need to group on (Creator and User_Involved).

I managed to write an SQL query that gives the correct results, however i'm unable to translate it into a Hibernate version.

The issue mostly comes down to JPA unable to perform unions.

The Query in question:

```
/** assumption 1 is owed to creator **/

select sum(owed_to_you) as owed_to_you, friend_id
from
(
/** you created **/
select sum(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 0 THEN -amount ELSE amount END) as owed_to_you, friend_involved as friend_id
from iou
where
  creator = 3

group by friend_involved

union all

/** someone else created **/
select sum(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 1 THEN -amount ELSE amount END) as owed_to_you, creator as friend_id
from iou
where
  friend_involved = 3

group by creator) as theunion

group by friend_id
```

Besides loading all Ious into memory and sorting it that way, I'm completely stumped. I've done a lot of research today and learned a lot, however, i still have not made progress.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Fyi JPA allows calling native sql queries with the entity manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the two queries separately and combine the results in Java-code.